# How to simulate the hardware shutter button in the Emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

In addition to soft keys, I'd like to test how my app responds to the hardware shutter buttons (e.g. various states half-pressed, fully-pressed, button-release. etc...).

The emulator does not seem to have a hardware shutter button (unless I am missing something).
So, in the absence of an actual device, how can I test this functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The F7-Key is mapped in the emulator to the camera shutter-key fully pressed and the F6-Key is mapped to the half-pressed shutter-key.

Both shortcuts are not supported in Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone (but I have no idea why they did this limitation...)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff754352%28v=vs.105%29.aspx gives a list of supported emulator hot-keys. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have specific buttons in your application and simply invoke the method wired to the event handler. For example:

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed +=new EventHandler(CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed);

    CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed(this, new EventArgs());
}

void CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("HALF_PRESSED");
}
```

But that would only help if you are willing to have a dedicated "test panel" in your application that will control these events.

Answer (score 0):

As with everything else hardware related, you kinda can't ;-) So hurry on the mailman to deliver your phone already!

Comment: It would have been nice for them to at least provide a button on the emulator so that you can test the interaction.